# Factorization of polynomial $x^{n}-a^{n}\in\mathbb{C}[x]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

This is my first post here. Mathematics is my hobby. As young I did go through the usual amount of calculus and bit of real analysis. Nowadays I am getting into algebra and more serious analysis.

I have a trouble with this exercise. It goes..

Let $a\in\mathbb{C}$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{+}$. Show that polynomial $x^{n}-a^{n}\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ can be factorized as
$$
x^{n}-a^{n}=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (x-e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{n}}a).
$$

I tried to use polynomial division algorithm, but with bad luck. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. What are the solutions of $x^n = a^n$? In other words, what are the $n^{th}$ roots of $a^n$?
2. Use polar representation for $a$: $a = re^{i\theta}$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

If $x^n - a^n = 0$, then $x^n = a^n$, and so you need $n^{\mathrm{th}}$-roots of $a^n$.

Use [Euler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) and [de Moivre's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula).